# Create JAR file from Jersey application

Tags: java, apache, glassfish, jersey

I developed an application using Jersey. I wrote  some function that respond to the properly http request. Everything going well until I use Eclipse because I use this class to "create" the locally server

```
String baseUrl = "http://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":8032/"; 
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(baseUrl);
server.start();
```

Now I want to crate a JAR file for upload it on a external server but, when I run the JAR file (also locally), it doesn't work. I thought that, when I double tap my JAR file, a server start (at least locally) because the code above is included and it will start all we need.

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't double click on the jar if it's a glassfish server application.

They should go in the /lib folder of glassfish, start the server and your code should deploy the same way as it does in Eclipse.

Comment: so I have to put my JAR file into (mac OSX) gslassfish/lib ? Beacause there are a lot of file inside this folder. My app is written in Java and it isn't a web project

Comment: Yeah this folder is where your jar should be being deployed.  How are you running it from eclipse?  Are you using ant or maven?  If it's not a web project do you have an existing web project that is then calling this code?  If not, why is it running on a application server?

Comment: When I run the app on Eclipse, I simply run the class that contain the above code. I'm using simply Jersey libs (downloaded form here ). I don't have web project because, if I want to test the http response, I only have to write the correct URL (using locahost:ports) into web-browser

Comment: When you say you "run the class that contains the code" - is it a class that has a main method?  When you run it locally do you edit a web.xml file so when you go to localhost:port/application maps to the project you want it to?

Comment: Yes, the code is written in a main method but I haven't to edit nothing. All I need to be able to send http request is to write the correct URL on web-browser after made server running. I don't have XML files in my project. It's work fine and it is wonderful, I'd like this to happend when I run JAR file.

Comment: Ah ok, if it's got a main method then, you can just run it with `java -jar className` in the command prompt - I just saw your question was tagged with Glassfish.